# Is it possible to add an additional meeting to an existing Sharepoint meeting workspace?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, sharepoint

Given you have a sharepoint meeting workspace with a recurring meeting linked to Outlook and the meeting occurs every Monday at 1pm

Is it possible to add an additional meeting date to that workspace, like a one-of Tuesday meeting at 2pm?

Comment: I assume Office and Sharepoint 2007?

Comment: Yes, Office and SP 07

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible, I just tried it and it works fine to me. But I have office 2010.

Edit: I have a recuring meeting every morning at 9. So from monday to friday, I'm not available for an hour. What I've done, I went in Sharepoint, setup another meeting apointment with another person and it works fine. The only thing I have is 2 meeting at the same time but Outlook let it go thru. As I said, I have Office 2010 so maybe the functionnality is not the same as 2003/07.

Comment: Mind sharing with us how? Might be useful info ;-)

Comment: How do you set up another meeting from within SP?

Comment: I click on the left side menu, on Calendar. I hit the day I want to set the meeting. Then, I click on "Actions" and then, Connect with Outlook. My Outlook will open with my own calendar, my shared calendar and my Sharepoint calendar. I just need to add my meeting/appointment as I usualy do in Outlook and et voila! I get a reminder on my Outlook. Not on my Blackberry tho (Not on the BES but I have a mail forwarding on it)